# Reactive data with vue-chartjs and Pinia stores

Tags: javascript, vue.js, chart.js

I am new at combining the use of a Pinia store data and vue-chartjs to create reactive charts. I'm using [this example](https://stackblitz.com/github/apertureless/vue-chartjs/tree/main/sandboxes/reactive?file=src%2FApp.vue) as a guide but struggling to have the chart reactive to changes in the store.

I change the Pinia store data in another component using a reactive form, and can see the store data changing, but the chart not updating.

I am rendering a chart with the following component:

```
<script setup>
import { storeToRefs } from 'pinia'
import { useStore} from '@/store/pinia-store-file';
import {
    Chart as ChartJS,
    CategoryScale,
    LinearScale,
    PointElement,
    LineElement,
    Title,
    Tooltip,
    Legend
} from 'chart.js';
import { Line } from 'vue-chartjs';

ChartJS.register(
    CategoryScale,
    LinearScale,
    PointElement,
    LineElement,
    Title,
    Tooltip,
    Legend
);  

const store = useStore();

const storeData= storeToRefs(store);
const labels = [...Array(storeData.arr.value.length).keys()];

const data = {
  labels: labels,
  datasets: [
    {
      label: 'Data One',
      backgroundColor: '#f87979',
      data: storeData.arr.value
    }
  ]
}

const options = {
  responsive: true,
  maintainAspectRatio: false
}



</script>

<template>

  <Line :data="data" :options="options" />

</template>
```

I've tried wrapping the store variable in `ref()` but I think I need to re-render the chart?  I'm struggling to apply the above example to a Pinia store state and updating when the store is change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't set data as response. Please use [computed](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/computed.html)

This code can solve the problem:

```js
<script setup>
import { storeToRefs } from 'pinia'
import { useStore} from '@/store/pinia-store-file';
import {
    Chart as ChartJS,
    CategoryScale,
    LinearScale,
    PointElement,
    LineElement,
    Title,
    Tooltip,
    Legend
} from 'chart.js';
import { Line } from 'vue-chartjs';
import { computed } from "vue"

ChartJS.register(
    CategoryScale,
    LinearScale,
    PointElement,
    LineElement,
    Title,
    Tooltip,
    Legend
);  

const store = useStore();

const storeData= storeToRefs(store);

const data = computed(() => ({
  labels: [...Array(storeData.arr.value.length).keys()],
  datasets: [
    {
      label: 'Data One',
      backgroundColor: '#f87979',
      data: storeData.arr.value
    }
  ]
}))

const options = {
  responsive: true,
  maintainAspectRatio: false
}



</script>

<template>

  <Line :data="data" :options="options" />

</template>
```

Comment: you also don't need to use `storeToRefs` because the `useStore` itself returns a `Reactive`

Comment: If I remove `storeToRefs()` it stops being reactive. Do I need to change something else to avoid using it?

Comment: it's weird that basically `useStore` is the response. what version of pinia are you using. in the store file do you export `defineStore`?

Comment: oh i thought you should remove `storeToRefs` and replace `storeData.arr.value.length` with `storeData.arr.length` and `storeData.arr.value` with `storeData.arr`